# Map several ViewModel types to same view type

Tags: caliburn.micro

We use Caliburn.Micro for view location (ViewModel-first) with the default mapping convention for views and ViewModels, which is usually sufficient. I now need to create a mapping for an exception, where the same view type needs to be resolved for three different ViewModel types and haven't been able to figure out how to do this.

To illustrate:

The ViewModel types are
`MyApplication.ViewModels.ManageTheseThingsViewModel`
`MyApplication.ViewModels.ManageThoseThingsViewModel` 
`MyApplication.ViewModels.ManageOtherThingsViewModel`

and the view I want resolved for either of them is
`MyApplication.Views.ManageThingsView`.

I have looked at [Handling Custom Conventions](http://caliburnmicro.com/documentation/custom-conventions), and `ViewLocator.AddTypeMapping()` seems to be what I need, but the usage example given there is insufficiently detailed for me to adapt it for my case.

How can I achieve this?

Edit: I case that allows for a different easy way - the ViewModels all derive from a common base class.

Answer (score 0):

In Caliburn we have Name Transformer concepts.

http://caliburnmicro.com/documentation/name-transformer

refer this link once and implement using Regular expressions.

This will help you for this types.